# Can enum instances declare their own public methods?

Tags: java, enums

Please consider the following code sample:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    FIRST {
        @Override
        public void someMethod() {
            ...
        }
    },

    SECOND {
        @Override
        public void someMethod() {
            ...
        }

        public void someOtherMethod() {
            ...
        }
    };


    public abstract void someMethod();
}
```

Is it possible to call `someOtherMethod()`? I tried `MyEnum.SECOND.someOtherMethod()` but the IDE could not resolve it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Remember, you should treat enums as *instances* of a type. If the method isn't defined in the type, then it won't be accessible. To me, this looks like an object-specific method, which I don't think can be called from anywhere outside of the object itself... And in fact, I'm not sure if something like this would be possible outside of an `enum`

Comment: @user3580294 Wow, I've never heard of object specific method before. I couldn't find any documentation on it when I googled "java object specific method". Is there any documentation available on it? I did manage to compile the above snippet using javac (taking out the "...")

Comment: Check out this article on advanced enum usage. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html.

Comment: @Spundun Sorry about that; that was a term I made up to describe the scope of the method, and as far as I know isn't an "official" Java term. That wording just made sense to me because it's a method that's only defined for a particular instance of a type.

Comment: @Spundun Aaaand it turns out I was wrong. Look at ajb's answer.

Comment: @user3580294 Your understanding was good enough for normal Java programmers.  I'm a compiler maintainer (for a different language), so I'm used to reading language specifications and finding obscure minute details that only compiler writers would care about.

Comment: @ajb Thanks; I'm always looking to improve though. Seems like a close reading of the JLS is in order for the next time I find a chunk of time... Looking into possibly working with compilers in the future, and learning this kind of thing seems like it'd be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyEnum.SECOND.someOtherMethod()` is illegal because of this rule pertaining to the class bodies on `enum` constants:

> Instance methods declared in these class bodies may be invoked outside
>   the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in
>   the enclosing enum type.  [JLS §8.9.1]

So since `someOtherMethod()` doesn't override a `MyEnum` method, you can't invoke it outside of `MyEnum`.  You could, however, invoke it somewhere in the body of `SECOND`, and you might even be able to invoke it from the body of one of the other `enum` constants like `FIRST`, although I haven't tried it and frankly that would be a bit weird.